# Is this the most efficient way to get the contents of a single column in a row in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-re

I have a panda's dataframe where I cannot guarantee the order of the columns, the exact names of the columns or even if all the columns will exist.

I need to be able to process each row in the data frame and extract the values for certain columns.

At the moment I am doing it by searching the panda's series.axes list for a string that matches a regex like below ( I've simplified error handling in this example )

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():     
    
    #get the name of the column that matches the regex from the axes list           
    matching_string = [string for string in row.axes[0].tolist() if re.match('^myregexp *', string)]
           
           # check we only have one match before proceeding to print the value
           if len(matching_string) == 1:
               print(row[matching_string[0]])
           else:
              print('something went wrong')
```

Would this be the most efficient way? I couldn't work out how to put the regex directly into row['column_name'].

I know I can filter the column names at a dataframe level, but that wouldn't necessarily guarantee order if some of the columns are missing and therefore I couldn't reference them by index, i.e

`row[3]`

Comment: Can you give a small example of the data? Could you expect several matches? What should happen then?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, I think you should test your condition outside of the loop. You can also use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
# .squeeze() convert a one column DataFrame to a Series
sr = df.filter(regex='^myregexp *').squeeze(axis=1)
if isinstance(sr, pd.DataFrame):
    print('something went wrong')
else:
    # do stuff here
    for row in sr:
        print(row)
```

Comment: It's interesting that both too many and no columns return a DataFrame. My first thought was that only multiple columns would return a DataFrame. I'd probably still test for `isinstance(sr, pd.Series)` (and invert the test) in case the behavior of `squeeze` changes in the future ;)

Comment: The documentation is clear about that: *DataFrames with a single column or a single row are squeezed to a Series. Otherwise the object is unchanged.*. So a 0 dimension dataframe leave untouched.

Comment: I know, but this is a bit unexpected. I'd think that converting to Series should be the best option. Maybe there should be a parameter for that. It could event be reduced to a scalar if needed.